# Affine set characterization

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

We say that a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is $\textit{affine}$ if
$$
(\forall x_1,x_2 \in S)(\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R})\ \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 \in S.
$$

Now, there is a theorem which states that a set $S$ is affine if and only if every finite affine combination of points in $S$ is also an element of $S$. I've tried proving this, but a special case baffles me so I looked around in literature, but everywhere I looked the authors say that it is sufficient to prove this statement in the exact way that we would prove the statement for convex sets. However, one detail in that proof isn't clear to me.

My proof: One side of the equivalence is trivial. For the other side, assume $S$ is affine. Then we use induction. The case $k=2$ follows from the definition of an affine set. Then we assume that the statement holds for $k-1$. Let $x_1,\dots,x_k \in S$, $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k = 1$.

Obviously $\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_{k-1} = 1- \lambda_k$. Now we have

$$
\lambda_1 x_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k x_k = (1-\lambda_k)\left( \frac{\lambda_1}{1-\lambda_k}x_1 + \cdots + \frac{\lambda_{k-1}}{1-\lambda_k}x_{k-1} \right) + \lambda_k x_k,
$$
which is an element of $S$ because

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{\lambda_i}{1-\lambda_k}=1,
$$

which means that

$$
x':=\frac{\lambda_1}{1-\lambda_k}x_1 + \cdots + \frac{\lambda_{k-1}}{1-\lambda_k}x_{k-1} \in S,
$$

and then

$$
(1-\lambda_k)x'+ \lambda_k x_k \in S.
$$

However, what if $\lambda_k=1$? I've tried proving the statement in this case, but haven't succeeded. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

you can choose any $\lambda_i \neq 0$, then you have：
$(1-\lambda _i)(\sum\limits_{n=1,n\neq i}^{k}\frac{\lambda _n}{1-\lambda _i}x_n)+\lambda _i x_i$
because $\sum\limits_{n=1,n\neq i}^{k}\frac{\lambda _n}{1-\lambda _i}=1$
$x'=\sum\limits_{n=1,n\neq i}^{k}\frac{\lambda _n}{1-\lambda _i}x_n \in S $

and then $(1-\lambda _i)x'+\lambda_i x_i \in S$ 
This completes the proof.

Comment: But for $i\neq k$, $\lambda_i$ doesn't have to be $0$ because they are reals.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. So you can choose the first solution. You can choose any $ \lambda_i \neq 0$